# How to cast from org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection in java 1.8

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

How to cast from org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection in java 1.8. At present i am using like this and got the following exception.

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast
>   to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

```
session = getHibernateSession();
conn = getConnection(session);
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
oracleConnection = conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `Connection.unwrap()` on `WrappedConnectionJDK8`, very unfortunately. You have to call [`WrappedConnection.getUnderlyingConnection()`](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/unzip/unzip/org/jboss/ironjacamar/jdbc-local/1.2.0.CR1/jdbc-local-1.2.0.CR1-javadoc.jar-unzip/org/jboss/jca/adapters/jdbc/WrappedConnection.html#getUnderlyingConnection()) instead. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51171204/521799). In your case:

```
OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) 
    ((WrappedConnectionJDK8) conn).getUnderlyingConnection();
```

Alternatively, if you cannot access the `WrappedConnectionJDK8` type, just use reflection:

```
OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) 
    conn.getClass().getMethod("getUnderlyingConnection").invoke(conn);
```

I know...

Comment: WrappedConnectionJDK8 i am not able to import, which jar i need to include for this.

Comment: @user3292629: I don't know your project setup. Surely, you can ask someone in your team how to access that class. Otherwise, there's always the option of using reflection. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @ Lukas Eder: I added the respective jar, but after that i am getting the following error.
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast to org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8

Comment: https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.jboss.ironjacamar/ironjacamar-jdbc/1.4.8.Final/source-code. This is the jar i am using. @ Lukas Eder

Comment: Quite apparently, you've loaded the class twice and you're not referencing the right one. No clue if you're using OSGi or whatever, which could lead to this kind of problem.

Comment: i have two jars. One is ironjacamar 1.4.8 final and the other one is ojdbc6. So do i need to remove ojdbc6 ? @Luke Eder

Comment: Ehm... Nope :) If you really don't know how to solve this on your own, I suggest you use the reflection approach I've documented in my answer.

Comment: oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) 
         
    conn.getClass().getMethod("getUnderlyingConnection").invoke(conn);

requestDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(
      "SQL NAME", oracleConnection);




This is the code i am using,but when using this getting invalid argument error.

This is the oracle api that i  am using which accepts SQLName and java.sql connection. 
createDescriptor(SQLName name, java.sql.Connection conn)

Exception 
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to construct descriptor: Invalid arguments.  oracleConnection is coming as null. Any help? @Luke Eder

Comment: This is how i am creating the connection. 

    


`protected Connection getConnection(Session session) throws SQLException{
        Connection connection = null;
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            
         connection =((SessionImpl)session).connection();
        }
        return connection;
    }`
@Luke Eder

Comment: That's another option. You can answer your own question with how you obtained the connection, it will be useful for future visitors. That other issue you found is an unrelated problem, please ask a new question.

Comment: I have created a new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54684109/oracle-connection-coming-as-null
@Luke Eder