# Oracle Connection coming as null

Tags: java, oracle, database-connection

I am creating a  connection and trying to type cast that to OracleConnection, but when trying to do so it is coming as null. I am using java 1.8, In 1.6 it was working fine .

Connection Creation Method.

```
protected Connection getConnection(Session session) throws SQLException{
    Connection connection = null;
    if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
        //connection =((SessionFactoryImplementor)session.getSessionFactory()).getConnectionProvider().getConnection();
        connection =((SessionImpl)session).connection();
    }
    return connection;
}
```

DAOImpl Method where i am trying to assign the Connection object to Oracle Connection.

```
session = getHibernateSession();
            conn = getConnection(session);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) 
                    conn.getClass().getMethod("getUnderlyingConnection").invoke(conn);
            requestDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(
                    "sqlname", oracleConnection );
            arrStruct = new STRUCT[arlVehicleDetailsVOs.size()];
```

**conn object value**: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@66f4ec

But here the oracleConnection is coming as null. Ca n you please help what exactly needs to be changed to resolve this issue. The exception i am getting is invalid arguments passed.

**Exception**: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to construct descriptor: Invalid arguments

Comment: Are you actually putting `"SQL Name"` there?

Comment: Nope, my procedure name i am putting @ Luke Eder

Comment: OK, with a closer look, this is still the same question as your previous one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54652524/521799. You're still calling `unwrap()` on that JBoss `WrappedConnectionJDK8`, which I explained to you doesn't work. Please use the reflection approach I've mentioned in my other question. Have you at least tried it?

Comment: 1) Why procedure name it should be type name. 2) are you sure you the if condition is true

Comment: @Luke Eder, i tried that as well yesterday itself, but still the oracleConnection was coming as null only. i tried without if condition. i will post the updated code.

Comment: @Luke Eder: I have edited the code and posted the one i am using. Please take a look.

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz : i have changed the code, not using if condition.

Comment: @LukasEder : Any Help?

Comment: @LukasEder : Any help boss? Not able to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Lukas Eder: Any help on this issue